# Angular : Share data returned from factory between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I havea factory call HTTP end point to fetch user:

```
.factory('me', function($resource, VAS_API_URL, $q) {
  return {
    getUser: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var url = VAS_API_URL + 'api/me';
      $resource(url)
        .get(function(user) {
          deferred.resolve(user);
        }, function(response) {
          deferred.reject(response);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
})
```

I use this `factory` in many `controllers` and, i bind the data to the `DOM` successfully, but at times i want to use the data returned from the `factory` in my `controller` like to save the user name with a notification so i had to do the following:

```
.controller('createNotificationCtrl', function($scope, VAS_API_URL, me) {
  var Burl = VAS_API_URL + 'api/notification';

  $scope.profile = me.getUser();
  $scope.profile.then(
    function(user) {
      $scope.owner = user;
      $scope.item = {};
      $scope.item.message = $scope.message;
      $scope.item.owner = $scope.owner.displayName;
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
})
```

I had to creat `$scope.item = {};` in the factory call so i could get the `displayName` then send the object to save a notification but what if i want to save also another filed from another factory. How it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory should create the object and hold it as a state.

The controller's should use the reference from the factory and update it for everyone.

factory code sample:

```
this.stateObj = {};
....
....
this.getUser = function(){
    var promise = $http.get(url);
    promise.then(function(res){
       // update stateObj
    });
    return promise;
}
```

ctrl code sample:

```
factory.getUser().then(function(res){
   $scope.stateObj = factory.getStateObj();
});
```

Comment: But, my question was how to use the data returend out of the factory call scope, and within the controller scope.

Comment: I've showed you how to get the data from the factory in this line `$scope.stateObj = factory.getStateObj();` .Now all you need to do is use it in your view\controller the way you want to.